# TFS 2008: Checkin cannot proceed because the policy requirements have not been satisfied

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

We have a project with many developers. Some use Visual Studio 2008 Professional with TFS Client, others use Visual Studio 2008 Team System.

We have checkin policies that there should be a comment and it should be connected to a work item.

Some of the developers with Visual Studio 2008 Professional are getting the following error:

> Checkin cannot proceed because the policy requirements have not been satisfied

Even if the conditions have been satisfied. For a while we were also getting this on a VS Team System installation, but that seems to have solved itself.

Any Ideas why we are getting this error? Are we missing an update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the check-in policy to require a comment is part of the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx), not directly part of Visual Studio.  Could it be that some of your users haven't installed the power tools?