# TFS Shell Extension Policy Failure

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

Whenever I use the TFS Windows Shell Extension to check a file in, it pops up a window asking me to provide the description for the changeset.  But when I click OK, it gives me another warning dialog that says

Policy Failure
   Checkin cannot proceed because the policy requirements have not been satisfied.

[image]

But the problem is, the only requirement we have is to give a checking description and I've done that.
Is there some reason why the shell extension is giving this warning?  It doesn't happen when I check in from VS directly.

Google has been unhelpful.

Details:  Everything is the 2015 versions of TFS, VS, TFS Power Tools, etc.

**EDIT:** The only policy requirement we have is that you must provide a changeset description.  The changeset description provided is actually saved, so the problem isn't that it's ignoring the changeset description.

At this point, I've given up.  Whenever I check in via the Explorer menu, I click the "Override policy failure" checkbox and give it a reason of :-P

Comment: Does it occur if you uninstall and reinstall TFS Power Tools?

Comment: uninstall/reinstall did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471826/tfs-2008-checkin-cannot-proceed-because-the-policy-requirements-have-not-been-s), you need to make sure all uses have installed the TFS Power tool.

> I believe the check-in policy to require a comment is part of the TFS Power Tools, not directly part of Visual Studio. Could it be that some of your users haven't installed the power tools?

Comment: I just checked and I have TFS Power Tools installed (I just edited the question to reflect that).